# C++ template parameter deduction by assignment

Tags: c++, templates, matrix

I want something very simple: a template function that contains the template parameter just in the return type, but not in the function parameters. The template parameter should then be deduced from an assignment when calling the function.

To be specific, let's consider a function creating random matrices of type   `MatType<T>` of a certain dimension. The template parameter T is the numeric type of the matrix (e.g. matrix of doubles, floats, ints, etc.):

```
template<typename T>
MatType<T>
randmat(int m, int n)
{ // create MatType<T> of size m x n, fill with random numbers and return it.}
```

Now for some reason template parameters cannot a priori be deduced from the return type, so when I use this function I have to call it as e.g.

```
MatType<double> M = randmat<double>(10,10);
```

I however would like a way around this, i.e. call the function just as

```
MatType<double> M = randmat(10,10);
```

i.e. have the function determine the template parameter from the return type `MatType<double>`.
This is only partly because I am lazy, as the template parameter in my case can become long and nasty.

This might seem like a stupid question that many people have asked before, but I didn't really find any satisfactory answer other than saying that it's not possible. I am however using a matrix library called [armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net), which has template functions with exactly [that ability](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#randu_randn_standalone), so I know it's possible (but somehow too complicated and time consuming for me to extract how it's done from the source code).

Can this be done with some traits or template meta-programming? Also how would one deal with function calls without assignment like `randmat(10,10);`?

Thanks

Comment: `auto M = randmat<foo>(...);`

Comment: This might depend on what copy constructors are available for `MatType<double>` and/or whether they are `explicit`.

Comment: The documentation of armadillo you link to shows `mat  A = randu<mat>(5,6);` as an example. Thus, you specify the type of the matrix in the template argument there

Comment: Using `randmat(10,10)` without an explicit element or matrix type is actually a bad idea, as in effect you won't be able to use `randmat(10,10)` reliably in a compound expression. For example, take this simple compound expression: `M = 2 + randmat(10,10)`, where the underlying element type produced by `randmat(10,10)` is effectively unknown.  Should it be integer, float, double, complex, etc ?  To avoid this problem, Armadillo [requires](http://arma.sf.net/docs.html#randu_randn_standalone) the matrix type to be explicitly specified. The default template parameter happens to be `<mat>`

Comment: @Rumburak yes unfortunately the doc doesn't mention that it also works without specifying the template parameter, so `mat A = randu(5,6);` also works. And as @mtall points out, in that case the default template parameter is just `mat` which is a matrix of doubles.

Comment: @mtall OK I agree there might be situations where jxh's or M.M.'s solutions leave ambiguities. But the addition operator could be overloaded to take objects of type `randmat` and be designed accordingly, there's no ambiguity in that then. I prefer to take the pragmatic approach and worry about that when I need it (which I doubt). But for the general reader this is certainly a good heads up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this effect more efficiently is to defer computation of the random values until the return type is known. You can achieve this with a proxy object whose only purpose is to detect the type being assigned to, and then perform the computation using a type appropriate object.

```
struct RandMatType {
    const int m_;
    const int n_;
    RandMatType (int m, int n) : m_(m), n_(n) {}
    template <typename T>
    operator MatType<T> () const {
        MatType<T> M;
        //... fill M
        return M;
    }
};

RandMatType randmat(int m, int n) {
   return RandMatType(m, n);
}
```

In the above code, `randmat()` first returns the proxy of type `RandMatType`. Then, during assignment, the proxy object is converted to target type. The conversion operator then assumes the conversion type is the type of matrix to use.

Comment: That's a very smart way of doing it! Until actual assignment to a specific Matrix object of some particular type, RandMatType only stores the relevant info, namely the dimensions (and maybe the probability distribution, etc.) and only at assignment, the random matrix gets constructed. I didn't think of using a custom conversion, those are still a bit weird to me :-) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking is not exactly possible, but some aspects of it might work "by chance" depending on the domain of the problem.

In the line

```
MatType<double> M = randmat(10,10);
```

it's not possible (in C++) to deduce the template parameter based on the type of `M`, because by the language rules, *first* the RHS is constructed, only *then* assignment (or copy construction as is the case here) happens. So at construction, the later operation doesn't have a say.

However, assume that `randmat(10, 10)` returns a matrix of `double`s, and that `MatType<T>` has a copy constructor taking a const reference to `MatType<U>` (for some other type `U`). Then this gives you not exactly what you asked, but a similar bottom-line effect. This is what is happening in Armadillo, BTW.

---

Another - particularly elegant solution by @jxh - is to use lazy computation, and defer calculating anything until assignment to a concrete type.

I have to say I am not crazy about it. As you write in the question, you could perform an operation on the temporary returned object without any assignment, e.g.,

```
randmat(10,10).foo();
```

Consequently, you *must* commit in your code what the logical default specific returned type is. Given that you do so, and most algebraic/random-generation operations are far more complicated than a simple copy-conversion, it seems like a complicated overkill to me in this case.

Comment: This is really what armadillo does? It creates a double random matrix and then converts it to other types? How would this work for complex types then (you are lacking the imaginary part)? In any case, thx for the clarification!

Comment: I just noticed that assigning armadillo's randn to a complex matrix `cx_mat = randn(10,10)` without specifying the template parameter doesn't work (static assert fail at compile time). Apparently when not specifying the default is `double` and the assignment of the resulting random double matrix to a complex one is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution that avoids duplication is:

```
auto m = randmat<double>(10, 10);
```

If you really want to use your original proposed syntax, you will have to make `randmat` be a placeholder which just passes information through to a point at which you know the destination type. For example:

```
struct randmat
{
    int x, y; 
    randmat(int x, int y): x(x), y(y) {}
};

template<typename T>
struct MatType
{
   int x, y;

   MatType(randmat r): x(r.x), y(r.y)
   {
       // call your random generation code here; can use T
   }
};

int main()
{
   MatType<double> m = randmat(10, 10);
}
```

Comment: Concur. Similar to my offering, but the conversion is done via `MatType` constructor rather than a `randmat` conversion operator.

Comment: Indeed, that's also a nice solution! But you need to explicitly add an additional constructor to the matrix class (which I can't, as I am using a library). Thanks any ways!

Answer (score 0):

One option is to return MapType

```
MatType<int>
randmat(int m, int n)
{ // create MatType<int> of size m x n, fill with random numbers and return it.}
```

And have a conversion operator to generate the required type

```
template<typename T>
struct MatType
{
   template<typename T>
   operator MatType<T>()
   {...}
};
```

Comment: So with this approach one would basically have to start from the top level, e.g. always generate complex double random matrices, which can then be downconverted to e.g. complex single, double, single, int, unsigned int, etc.
That seems like a pragmatic solution :-) yet not very efficient if you deal with complicated data types (in my case it would be fine though)